# Enthought Canopy installer does not create ~/Enthought directory in Linux

Tags: linux, enthought

I'm using openSUSE 12.3 64bit. I successfully installed Canopy when it was released, and since then I have uninstalled it by deleting both `~/Enthgout` and `~/Canopy`.

Now I am trying to install Canopy again, installer works without any problem but it does not generate `~/Enthgout` directory anymore. I tried to delete any cache folders but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer does not generate the ~/Enthought directory. It is created during first startup. More info here: http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment

Comment: You are right. I'm having problem with installation of Canopy in GNU/Linux, and I thought this was the culprit, but it was apparently not. I will create another question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513299/cannot-launch-canopy-in-gnu-linux-opensuse-12-3