# Cannot launch Canopy in GNU/Linux (openSUSE 12.3)

Tags: enthought

After installation, when I do

```
$ ~/Canopy/canopy
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/__boot__.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 1335, in main
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 1315, in send_bug_report
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/feedback/data_reporter.py", line 390, in start
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enaml/core/import_hooks.py", line 131, in load_module
    exec code in mod.__dict__
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/canopy/feedback/data_reporter_view.enaml", line 4, in 
    from pyface.api import clipboard
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/api.py", line 16, in <module>
    from about_dialog import AboutDialog
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/about_dialog.py", line 18, in <module>
    from toolkit import toolkit_object
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/toolkit.py", line 73, in <module>
    _init_toolkit()
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/toolkit.py", line 38, in _init_toolkit
    be = import_toolkit(ETSConfig.toolkit)
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/toolkit.py", line 31, in import_toolkit
    __import__(be + 'init')
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/ui/qt4/init.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pyface.qt import QtCore, QtGui, qt_api
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/qt/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    prepare_pyqt4()
  File "/home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/qt/__init__.py", line 16, in prepare_pyqt4
    import sip
ImportError: No module named sip
~/Canopy/canopy: command not found
```

When I do this

```
$ ~/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/bin/ipython
```

I get the following weird error:

```
zsh: /home/joon/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/bin/ipython: bad interpreter: /home/builder/jenkins/workspace/Canopy_App/ARCH/x86_64/label/L: no such file or directory
~/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/bin/ipython: command not found
```

I have tried to reinstall this about 10 times now but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run ipython from the user virtual environment, see these:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-
http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment

Regarding your Canopy startup problem, apparently you're telling Canopy to use PyQt (which is not installed) rather than PySide (which is, and is default); perhaps you are setting the `QT_API` environment variable. Does it help if you clear this first, or else set it thus?:
`export QT_API=pyside`

Comment: `export QT_API=pyside` did the trick. I remember Canopy worked well in previous installation of openSUSE (I have re-installed it to my ssd recently), so I wonder if `QT_API` was messed up for some reason. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I fixed this by replacing `Exec=/home/joon/Canopy/canopy %F` by `Exec=env QT_API=pyside /home/joon/Canopy/canopy %F` in `~/.local/share/applications/canopy.desktop`.